# How to get rid of artefact rectangles in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis

when inserting a map on the canvas of print composer and moving that map around,
quite often, there is a rectangle that cannot be deleted.

This rectangle is positioned at the initial place, where I draw my map first.

I thought, it is just a "on screen" problem, but in print, the rectangle is there as well.

Then I try to put it into the background, but this doesn't work either.

[image: How to get rid of this line?]

Comment: have you tried the refresh option.  sometimes this happens to me but i think it is to do with processor speed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a number of times as well. Try adding the map again. But before you move anything, make sure you click "Lock Layers" in the right hand side bar.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? From memory this was fixed at around version 2.2. The workaround for previous versions is to save your project and then reload it - that will remove the extra rectangle.